# rails console won't connect to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database.yml that uses environment variables, eg:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: <%= ENV['RAILS_DB_NAME'] %>
  pool: 5
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  username: <%= ENV['RAILS_DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RAILS_DB_PASS'] %>
```

However, when I use:

```
$ export RAILS_DB_NAME="rails_db"
$ rails c production
> User.all
I get an error:
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I can see my environement variable in the same console:

```
> ENV['RAILS_DB_NAME']
"rails_db"
```

But if I dump the active connection config it is nil:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
{:adapter=>"mysql2", :encoding=>"utf8", :reconnect=>false, :database=>nil, :pool=>5, :host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>3306, :username=>nil, :password=>nil}
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

How can I trace why rails app isn't getting the environment variables?

TIA!

Update: I should clarify that $ rails db works perfectly. It's only $ rails c that can't connect to db.

Update 2: When I clone down the project to a new folder and bundle install it works perfectly fine there. It *must* be something with my folder. Diff doesn't show any differences. Weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the fix - but I am not sure why this is a problem.. but.. rails doesn't like having a project in a folder named rails!

My rails project was in a folder:

```
/var/deployed/rails
```

when I rename it to:

```
/var/deployed/myapp
```

Then $ rails console works perfectly to talk to the db.

Weird!

Answer (score 1):

Its not so much Rails/ActiveRecord but MySQL is not allowing the connection. Why is your `username` and `password` not specified in `config/database.yml`?

Open a MySQL console and run this:

```
> grant all on rails_db.* to root@localhost;
```

(replace `rails_db` with whatever is your actual DB name.)

This will allow incoming connections based on the default `username=root` and a blank password. If you do end up specifying a `username` and `password` in your config, then re-run the grant statement with those credentials.

E.g.

```
> grant all on rails_db.* to root@localhost identified by 'somepassword';
```

Comment: Sorry, I left it out above. It is specified, also environment variables. And it isn't root. The error above is because all three places I call ENV[] (database, username, password) come up nil. The database config works perfectly is I run $ rails db. It's only $ rails c that doesn't.